# Mensaje de Error, manejando funciones con POO y PHP.. Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysqli

```
class OperacionesAlumno{
private $server = 'localhost';
private $usuario = 'root';
private $pass = '';
private $bd = 'dbvasco';

public function Conectar(){
     $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','intranet');
     mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');  //permite que las tild
     return $conexion;
}

public function muestraGrupos(){
   $conexion = $this->Conectar();
   $sql = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * 'grupos'");
   return $sql->fetch_all();  // LINEA DE ERROR
}
```

Comment: Probaste quitando las comillas simples al nombre de la tabla? O cambiar `$sql = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * 'grupos'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)`

Comment: si, pero marca el mismo error, al mandar traer la función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu sentencia `SQL` tiene un error de sintaxis, y [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) en esos casos no devuelve un objeto, sino `FALSE`.

Te sugiero realizar dos acciones:

a) Cambia la construcción para que evalúe el valor devuelto en un IF, podría ser tan simple como esto:

```
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($miSentenciaSQL)) {
  printf("La selección devolvió %d filas.\n", $resultado->num_rows);
  $resultado->close();
} else {
  /* no utizes die en la vida real, acá maneja el error o informa al usuario. */
  die "$misqli devolvió FALSE";
}
```

b) corrige tu sentencia SQL (le falta la clausula `from`), supongo que lo que quieres en realidad es esto:

```
SELECT * from 'grupos'
```

Juntando ambas cosas, y haciendo otros pequeños cambios, podría quedar algo como esto:

```
public function muestraGrupos(){
   $conexion = $this->Conectar();
   if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * from `grupos`")) {
     $filas = $resultado->fetch_all();
     $resultado->close();
     return $filas;
   } else {
     return FALSE;
   {
}
```

Comment: de acuerdo, muchas gracias, disculpa y para imprimir valores de la tabla en un <select> por ejemplo: si del modo php procedular seria con un foreach, para el modo orientado a objetos como cambian ese tipo de funciones,

Comment: dado que `fecth_all()` devuelve un array, igual podes utilizar `foreach`, o hacer un bucle con llamadas a `fetch_row()` o `fecth_array()`. Si no te queda claro, eso bien vale otra pregunta en el sitio.

Comment: de acuerdo, gracias ahorita pongo el bucle que intentaba poner pero no me imprime en <select>. Mando a traer la función pasada a un formulario,,